# How to make a Progress bar/Container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, progress

I am creating a website that involves people depositing items into the site, there will be a cap at 100 items. I am looking for a progress bar, horizontal or vertical I don't really mind, that increases as items are deposited into the site.

For now I am in need of help to get the progress bar working, going from 0 - 100%. I will worry about connecting the percentage of the progress bar and items deposited later.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post any code of what you've tried already? We don't write code on request. Instead we help those with specific coding issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 has a  element that does a very simple version of this.

It is used as follows:

```
<progress value="22" max="100"></progress>
```

Documentation regarding this element is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_progress.asp)

Browser support is rock solid according to CanIUseIt.com:

> HTML5 progress element is fully supported in the following browsers: Firefox 16+, Chrome 8+, Safari 6+ and Opera 11+.

You can use javascript or your favorite framework to dynamically update it, and css to style it.

If you are looking to make something a little more sexy, there are numerous tutorials on the subject. [Here is one I like.](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/)

Let me know if you need any more help. Good luck!

Comment: I don't suppose you know how I would dynamically update it? If you do it would be great help.

Comment: There are MANY ways to do that. It all depends on what technology stack you are using. Every framework has a different way of accessing element data and modifying it, so to answer this I need to know what are you using? Plain javascript? jquery? ect...

Comment: If you want to use Jquery, the tutorial I posted has an excellent explanation to this question. See: "Animate the Progress" section in that tutorial and he walks step by step how to do it. Also, if my answer helped you please upvote/accept.

Comment: I have not started trying to do it yet. But I guess I would use plain JavaScript if that's the best way to go. I'm not too familiar with JavaScript and jquery sorry for not giving you more information on this

Comment: I would highly recommend using jquery at the bare minimum. JavaScript alone is much more difficult to do anything, and proven frameworks like jquery are very helpful with this type of thing. See the tutorial I posted.